# image slideshow starts blank

Tags: jquery, html

I created an image slideshow that includes text blocks for a homepage banner using a Jquery (I think) I found online. It works except it starts off blank, then cycles through the image. Here's a link to the preview page, https://www.3-gis.com/click-1-0-1?hs_preview=BQtmhLbk-11749548756

I looked at some similar threads but I don't know JS enough to follow.

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="container" style="display: none;">
<img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/home%20banner%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
<div class="text-block">
<center>
<h1>Faster fiber deployments<br>Complete network visibility</h1>
</center></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="display: none;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/mobile%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
<div class="text-block">
<center>
<h1>Your network data<br>When and where you need it</h1>
</center></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="display: none;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/dashboard%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
<div class="text-block">
<center>
<h1>Your network data<br>at your fingertips</h1>
</center></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)") .hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4000);
</script>
```

I want it to start with the first image displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your slideshow doesn't start fading-in an image until the interval of 4 seconds has passed. To overcome this you can trigger it manually using the following command:

```
$('#slideshow > div:first').fadeIn(500);
```

Here's an example:

```js
$('#slideshow > div:first').fadeIn(500);
setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="container" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/home%20banner%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
    <div class="text-block">
      <center>
        <h1>Faster fiber deployments<br>Complete network visibility</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: none;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/mobile%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
    <div class="text-block">
      <center>
        <h1>Your network data<br>When and where you need it</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: none;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/499849/home%20banners/dashboard%20rotate.jpg" class="responsive">
    <div class="text-block">
      <center>
        <h1>Your network data<br>at your fingertips</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```